# What do I need to do to obtain the gold viking helm?

Tags: achievements, temple-run-2

[image]

What do I need to do to obtain the gold viking helm? I did enough runs to get to the end but nothing happened. I have gotten two chests after I completed the challenge.

Answer (score 1):

You have to stay in the top 5% until the end of the global challenge because prizes are not awarded until then. At the time of this post (6 days left) the top 5% has moved from 152,000 to 164,000 which means you have to keep checking in to make sure you're still in the top 5%.

[image]